# Load postgis vectorlayer with AuthConfigId

Tags: qgis, postgis, pyqgis, authentication

I've tried to add a postgis-vector-layer in qgis 2.14.0 by using authentication (authConfigId) and PyQGIS.
When running the script I'm asked to login by username/password  instead of using authConfigID.
What is wrong with "uri.setConnection" ?

Example of the script:

```
uri.setConnection("host_name","5432","database_name", "4zoa91a" )  #"4zoa91a" = my_example_authConfigId
uri.setDataSource("table_name","geometry_column_name","key_column_name")
vLayer=QgsVectorLayer(uri.uri(),"layer_name", "postgres")
if vLayer.isValid() : print('layer is valid' )
QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayers([vLayer])
```

In developer cookbook there is no hint to solve the problem. 
In the QGIS api-documentation I discovered:

```
void QgsDataSourceURI::setConnection    (   const QString &     aHost,
        const QString &     aPort,
        const QString &     aDatabase,
        const QString &     aUsername,
        const QString &     aPassword,
        SSLmode     sslmode = SSLprefer,
        const QString &     authConfigId = QString()
```

Here username/password are required, but as I said, I've tried to use the AuthentificationConfigID instead. (Is no problem to load this layer in qgis via interface.).

(Further it would be nice to get a hint/link how to "read"/"apply" the qgis-api-documentation/structure.)

Comment: Have you tried something like, ("host_name","5432","database_name", None, None, authConfigId = "4zoa91a"), e.g. here https://github.com/bstroebl/DataDrivenInputMask/blob/master/ddmanager.py

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick information! This was the solution for the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I noted in my comment, try:

```
uri.setConnection("host_name","5432","database_name", None, None, authConfigId = "4zoa91a")
```

This plugin has an example using this method:

https://github.com/bstroebl/DataDrivenInputMask/blob/master/ddmanager.py